# Pattern match failure on a list in Haskell

Tags: list, design-patterns, haskell, match

I just started working with Haskell and stumbled on a problem. 
According to Haskell, I have a pattern match failure, but I fail to see how.
This is the code I try to execute:

```
statistics ::   [Int] -> (Int, Int, Int)
statistics [gradelist] = ( amountParticipants, average, amountInsufficient)
                        where
                            amountParticipants= length [gradelist]
                            average= sum[gradelist] `div` amountParticipants
                            amountInsufficient= length [number| number<- [gradelist], number<6]
```

I call 'statistics' with:

```
statistics[4,6,4,6]
```

this causes a pattern match failure, while I expect to see : (4, 5, 2)

```
statistics[6]
```

gives the answer : ( 1, 6, 0 ) (which is correct).
Can someone tell me why my first call causes this pattern match? Because I'm pretty sure I give a list as an argument

Comment: `[gradelist]` only matches one-element list. Use just `gradelist` throughout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you write `statistics [gradelist] = ...` you are pattern matching against a **singleton** list containing a sole element referred to as `gradelist`. Hence, your function is only defined for lists of length exactly 1 (such as `[6]`); it is undefined for the empty list (`[]`) or lists with two or more elements (such as `[4,6,4,6]`).

A correct version of your function would read

```
statistics :: [Int]     -> (Int, Int, Int)
statistics    gradelist =  (amountParticipants, average, amountInsufficient)
  where
    amountParticipants = length gradelist
    average            = sum gradelist `div` amountParticipants
    amountInsufficient = length [number| number <- gradelist, number < 6]
```

As @thoferon remarked, you will also need to make special arrangements for the case in which `gradelist` is empty, in order to avoid dividing by zero when computing `average`.

Comment: thanks for the fast reponse! Now I finally can continue working with this language ^^

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your `[gradelist]`'s by `gradelist` as said before. Also, you might want to match against the empty list with [], in order to avoid dividing by zero in `average`, like :

```
statistics [] = (0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The list syntax `[ ]` in a pattern deconstructs a list.  The pattern `[gradelist]` matches a list holding exactly one value, and it names the value in the list `gradelist`.  You get a pattern match failure if you try to call the function with a list holding four values.

To match a value without deconstructing it, use a variable as the pattern.